# Why do I keep losing Managed Metadata Service connection on Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, office-365

I have recently signed up for Office 365, and I want to use managed metadata and use them with key filters.

But when I have set it up and added a term list, and then try to use it, the connection is really unstable. It might work for a little while, but then 5 minutes later it's out again.

This happens the whole time, it's not just a temporary problem. Usually it doesn't work long enough for me to do any work, the service is interrupted before I can get anything done.

This might be unrelated, but it also says the terms are not valid terms when I try to search. At first it works, because I get the choices in a "tag tree", so it gets populated, select one of them and do the filtering. But when it shows filter results, the keyword goes red with a dotted line under it. Hovering says it's not a valid term.

So why does the Managed Metadata Service keep getting interrupted, and why does it report invalid terms (even though I get the terms from the term store the short while the service works)?

This is really frustrating, since Office 365 really seems like a good fit for our company other than this, but this instability might be the deal breaker...

Any help would be really appreciated! (Please remember that this is Sharepoint Online, so I'm not able to restart any IIS or anything like that which I saw suggestions for)

Answer (score 1):

I’ve tested the Term Store by creating a new group, new term set and new terms. I’ve added term set to a list with some test data. I’ve also created filters based on the terms and had it running for little over an hour without any problem.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

In March there where [others with issues with Term Store](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/227853/706620.aspx), posted to Microsoft Support and the Office 365 Community.  The correct way to deal with these issues is to ask Microsoft through their support channel found in Office 365 admin center > support > contact support.

[image] [image]

Add a new service request and specify your problem as much as possible with tenant URL and steps taken.